# Incorporating Conduit to ordinary functions

Tags: haskell, stream, conduit

I wrote a simple program in which I read a big XML file and do some
processing on the contents of the file and then save the processed
data in new file.

The original main function follows something like this:

```
main = do
  content <- B.readFile "/home/sibi/github/data/chennai.osm" 
  let tags = removeUnwanted $ parseTags content 
      hospitals = toHospital $ extractHospitalNode tags
  BL.writeFile "osmHospitals.json" (encode hospitals)
```

But this code eats up the full memory and takes a huge time to finish. So, I decided
to use conduit library for making the program run in constant memory.

But after reading the [conduit tutorial](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/snoyberg/library-documentation/conduit-overview), I still haven't got the idea
how to make the above program use the features of conduit library.

I figured out that I can use conduit's [sourceFile](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-1.0.13.1/docs/Data-Conduit-Binary.html#v%3asourceFile) which can stream the
content of the file. But then how to apply the function [parseTags](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tagsoup-0.13.1/docs/Text-HTML-TagSoup.html#v%3aparseTags) (which is a function from the TagSoup library) and other simple functions
to the streamed content now ?

Edit: The entire code is [here](https://github.com/psibi/rwh/blob/master/hospitals/hospital3.hs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a huge disconnect between the methodology of `parseTags` and the methodology of `conduit` and `pipes`: `parseTags` assumes it can access the next chunk of data purely, while `pipes`/`conduit` let you handle situations where that's impossible, such as streaming from a file. In order to mix parsing into `pipes`/`conduit` you must have a way to mix consuming a parse into steps which pull new chunks of data.

(I'll use `pipes` in the sequel because I'm more familiar with them, but the idea is transferable.)

We can see this disconnect in the types, though I'll begin with a slightly restricted version.

```
parseTags :: Lazy.ByteString -> [Tag Lazy.ByteString]
```

We can think of `Lazy.ByteString` as streaming apparatus all by itself, it is, after all, essentially just

```
type LazyByteString = [Strict.ByteString]
```

such that if we were generating the `Lazy.ByteString` ourselves then we could rely on the laziness of lists to ensure that we don't generate more than what `parseTags` needed in order to proceed (I'll assume, without looking, that `parseTags` is written so that it could incrementally parse a streaming structure like that).

```
sillyGen :: LazyByteString
sillyGen = gen 10 where
  gen 0 = []
  gen n = "<tag> </tag>" : gen (n-1)
```

Now the problem here is that the streaming behavior of a list depends crucially upon being able to generate the tail of the list *purely*. In the discussion so far there hasn't been any mention of a monad at all. Unfortunately, that cannot be true with a string being streamed from a file---we need to somehow integrate an IO action between each streamed chunk where we consider whether or not we've reached EOF and close the file as necessary.

This is exactly the realm of `pipes` and `conduit`, so let's look at what that do to solve that issue.

```
-- from pipes-bytestring
fromHandle :: Handle -> Producer' Strict.ByteString IO ()
```

We can think of `fromHandle` as being the "monadically-interwoven" equivalent to

```
Lazy.hGetContents :: Handle -> IO Lazy.ByteString
```

The types suggest a crucial difference between these two operations--`hGetContents` can be executed in exactly one `IO` action while when we pass a `Handle` to `pipes-bytestring`'s `fromHandle` it returns a type which is parameterized over `IO` but cannot be simply freed from it. This is exactly indicative of `hGetContents` using lazy IO (which can be unpredictable due to the use of `unsafeInterleaveIO`) while `fromHandle` uses deterministic streaming.

We can write a type similar to `Producer Strict.ByteString IO ()` as

```
data IOStreamBS = IOSBS { stepStream :: IO (Strict.ByteString, Either IOStreamBS ()) }
```

In other words we can think of `Producer Strict.ByteString IO ()` as not much more than an IO action which produces exactly the next chunk of the file and (possibly) a new action to get the next chunk. This is how `pipes` and `conduit` provide deterministic streaming.

But it also means that you cannot escape from the `IO` in one fell swoop—you have to carry it around.

---

We might thus want to adjust `parseTags`, which is capable of some generalization over its input, to just accept `Producer Strict.ByteString IO ()` as a `StringLike` type

```
parseTags :: StringLike str => str -> [Tag str]
```

Let's assume for argument that we've instantiated `StringLike (Producer Strict.ByteString IO ())`. That would mean that applying `parseTags` to our producer would provide us with a list of `Tag (Producer Strict.ByteString IO ())`.

```
type DetStream = Producer Strict.ByteString IO ()
parseTags :: DetStream -> [Tag DetStream]
```

For this to happen we would have had to peek into our `Producer` and cut it up into chunks without executing anything in the `IO` monad. By this point it should be clear that such a function is impossible---we couldn't even get the first chunk from the file without doing something in `IO`.

---

To remedy this situation, systems like `pipes-parse` and `pipes-group` have arisen which replace the function signature with something more like

```
parseTagsGrouped :: Producer Strict.ByteString IO () 
                 -> FreeT (Producer (Tag Strict.ByteString) IO) IO ()
```

which is scary looking but serves an identical purpose to `parseTags` except that it generalizes the list to a structure which allows us to execute arbitrary `IO` actions between each element. This kind of transformation, as the type shows, can be done purely and thus allows us to assemble our streaming machinery using pure combinations and only incur an `IO` step when we execute it at the end (using `runEffect`).

---

So, all said and done, it's probably not going to be possible to use `pipes` or `conduit` to stream to `parseTags`---it simply assumes that certain transformations can be done purely, pushing all the `IO` to one point in time, while `pipes`/`conduit` are basically mechanisms for spreading `IO` throughout a computation without too much mental overhead.

If you're stuck using `parseTags`, however, you can get by using lazy `IO` as long as you're careful. Try a few variations with `hGetContents` from `Data.ByteString.Lazy`. The primary problem will be that the file may close prior to the `unsafeInterleaveIO`'d operations actually getting around to reading it. You'll thus need to manage strictness very carefully.

Essentially that's the big difference between `pipes`/`conduit` and lazy IO. When using lazy IO, all of the "read a chunk" operations are made invisible and implicitly controlled by Haskell laziness. This is dynamic, implicit, and tough to observe or predict. In `pipes`/`conduit` all of this motion is made extraordinarily explicit and static, but it's up to you to manage the complexity.

Answer (score -1):

What if you try [System.IO](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/System-IO.html), read the file line by line and process it(or read parts of the xml file)?

Comment: Doesn't lazy evaluation come into play ? I think using conduit or pipes library is a better solution to this problem.

Comment: That was just a "what if...". Lazy evaluation is great in conduit but i don't like conduit. It seems ugly.